# Can "Multi-Touch" technology of iPhone identify 5 or 10 touches at the same time?

Tags: ios, multi-touch

Let say you use your 5 fingers to touch & open 5 apps in iPhone at the same time. If that is the case, then "can all 5 apps be opened at the same time?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, iOS multitouch will track 11 independent touch positions in the current SDK (iOS 7).

However, the springboard app won't launch but one app at a time, so the answer is no to having more than one app run due to precise multitouch tapping the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

While iOS devices support multiple finger inputs, they can only run one application at a time. If you try to open multiple apps at once, only the first tapped app will launch.